# C# DateTime.ToString with data format or pattern

Tags: c#, datetime

i am trying to understand how DateTime.ToString(Date pattern) work in .net framework, C#.

I changed my computer to have a short Date format like this yyyy.MM.dd.
Following is what I notice

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
```

`myDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` always return in the format of yyyy.MM.dd not yyyy/MM/dd
and
`myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` does return string in the format of yyyy-MM-dd

to have it return what i was looking for, this is what i need to do
`myDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")` ===> yyyy/MM/dd

Can anyone explain to me why it is doing that?
and is there any other way i can achieve the same result?

thanks....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**/** is considered a format specifier and is replaced just like **yyyy** is.

Read the information on the [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx):

> / = The default date separator defined
>   in DateSeparator.

Comment: thanks, i guess I have to manually escape the "/" character by putting single quote around them then.thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also escape single character using backslash:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
myDate.ToString("yyyy\\/MM\\/dd");
// or
myDate.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the behavior you're seeing because ["/" is a format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator).

If you look at the [custom date format settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) help, you'll see that "/" translates as the date separator for your culture.